# Standard metric describing % gain/loss normalized by the time of owning the security + Interactive Brokers implementation

Tags: investing, portfolio

If you sell the stock with 5% gain over 1 day it's not the same as if you sell it with 5% gain over a year.

Is there a standard metric / coefficient that normalizes that and how to do it in Interactive Brokers?

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. Your question seems reasonable, though I can't answer it. Please don't be put off by rude members of our site who apparently think it's OK to downvote a new users first question without explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bob Baerker says, the simplest is to just annualize the shorter investment.

More generally, you can annualize all the returns over the initial investment.

More accurately, you can use the Excel function `XIRR` to take account of when each return happened.

See the image of an Excel spreadsheet below for a slightly more complex example.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a quick comparison, just annualize the the shorter investment.  If you want to be more accurate then read on.

From Investopedia:

> > ROI and the Length of Time in an Investment
> >
> > ROI measures the bottom line return of any investment. However, ROI doesn't factor in the length of time an investment position is held. For example, if stock investment A has an ROI of 100% and investment B an ROI of 50%, on the surface, the 100% gain is the clear winner. But, if investment A took 10 years to achieve its 100% return while investment B took only one month to earn its 50% gain, investment A's return wouldn't be as impressive. The length of time a position is held must come into play when calculating the true return on any investment. For more on how time can impact the return on an investment, please read up on the compound annual growth rate or CAGR.

Here's the link for CAGR:

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cagr.asp